# Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation error on library code

Tags: c++, valgrind, ioctl

Hi I am currently fixing my valgrind errors and they are :

```
==11925== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==11925== 
==11925== 9 errors in context 1 of 1:
==11925== Syscall param ioctl(generic) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==11925==    at 0xF8B7F47: ioctl (syscall-template.S:84)
==11925==    by 0x1F770DAD: drmIoctl (in /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==11925==    by 0x1F7756E8: drmCommandWriteRead (in /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==11925==    by 0x3332C6AC: amdgpu_create_bo_from_user_mem (in /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x32A479F2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gallium-pipe/pipe_radeonsi.so)
==11925==    by 0x32A6E6B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gallium-pipe/pipe_radeonsi.so)
==11925==    by 0x2D8E8BD6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x2D8E05D4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x2D8DE2D4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x2D8DD2E7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x2D8DD940: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==    by 0x2D8D8875: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMesaOpenCL.so.1.0.0)
==11925==  Address 0xffeffed64 is on thread 1's stack
==11925==  in frame #3, created by amdgpu_create_bo_from_user_mem (???:)
==11925==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==11925==    at 0x329770B0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gallium-pipe/pipe_radeonsi.so)
```

In my program I have nothing to do with the files mentioned in the error code. I have read many posts about this problem, but in my case, the code line mentioned is **not even in my code** (I suppose it is in some library i use).

I appreciate any help !

Comment: It can be that library you use contains defects or that you used it in wrong way or that valgrind made a false positive. We do not see what you have and can't reverse engineer it from those messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite common to pass an uninitialized buffer to ioctl.

There is even an option in valgrind to ignore them:

```
--sim-hints=lax-ioctls
```

See the doc http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html

> lax-ioctls: Be very lax about ioctl handling; the only assumption is that the size is correct. Doesn't require the full buffer to be initialised when writing. Without this, using some device drivers with a large number of strange ioctl commands becomes very tiresome.

In brief, your error is (very likely) a false positive.

Comment: Thank you, i have been busting my head about this problem for way too long :(